# Where can I find documentation for the JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript

Ok, I'm getting really frustrated with Javascript. I have bought the books, found tons of videos on line, found a few good resources but still I feel like a little kid. I want the big boys version of the API and how to write real code.

Can some one please help me with the folowing
1) where can I find a real API
2) How do I really use this stuff so I can use it in the real world.
3) why is it so hard to find good information on this topic, there there some secreete website or book that is not made avaible to the general public or what.

Anyone please direct me to the right place.

Comment: 1. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript), 2. Practice, 3. Everyone's an expert.

Comment: It's unclear what you're really asking here.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is causing you problems with doing it?

Comment: Your frustration is palpable, but we'll need something more specific to help you with.

Comment: I still think this is the best free book out there to get started with JS and jQuery http://jqfundamentals.com/book/,

Comment: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/401979/36866) answer you find several links depending on what you are interested in. Start with the [ECMA262 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

Comment: Okay, I understand that this question is a bit vague, but it isn't off topic here.

Comment: @elclanrs and others, just be aware that the book isn't being maintained anymore and (at some point in the future) the content will end up at http://learn.jquery.com .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the Mozilla Developer Network has excellent documentation and guides for the JavaScript API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide

---

Futher to this, I highly recommend developing in Chromium/Google Chrome as they include an excellent set of JavaScript debugging tools including a console with auto-completetion. I used to use Firebug, but it's really quite clunky compared to what Chrome/ium offers.

**How is JavaScript used in the 'real world'?**

You need to consider that JavaScript is in no way a stand-alone entity; it is tightly integrated into the web browser model, complementing HTML, CSS and the browser. Newer features of JavaScript, and the server-side JavaScript environment, [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) are warping this, however for use in web browsers JavaScript still revolves around it's integration with other web components. In other words, you should probably start by making single pages that require scripted behaviour (eg. form validation), rather than thinking of a bigger application (of which JavaScript would only be a small component).

**Why is it so hard to find good information on this topic?**

I totally agree with you here. The short answer is that JavaScript is and has been evolving rapidly. Unless you're reading very recent books, your best bet is MDN if you're looking to browse, and Google (as always) if you're looking for something specific (or use Google to search MDN!).